# Maven Cargo: Integration Test runs before cargo deploys war

Tags: java, maven, maven-cargo, maven-failsafe-plugin

The integration `pom.xml` looks like

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                    <zipUrlInstaller>
                        <url>http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.16/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.16.zip</url>
                        <downloadDir>${project.build.directory}/downloads</downloadDir>
                        <extractDir>${project.build.directory}/extracts</extractDir>
                    </zipUrlInstaller>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <cargo.servlet.port>9090</cargo.servlet.port>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <deployables>
                    <deployable>
                        <groupId>com.yahoo.pryme_services.inventory</groupId>
                        <artifactId>services</artifactId>
                        <type>war</type>
                        <pingURL>http://localhost:9090/services/rest/hello</pingURL>
                    </deployable>
                </deployables>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-container</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-container</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The test looks like

```java
public class TestHelloIT {
    @Test
    public void testHello() {
        final String url = "http://localhost:9090/services/rest";
        final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        final WebTarget target = client.target(url).path("hello");
        final Invocation.Builder builder = target.request();
        final Response response = builder.get();

        assertEquals(Response.Status.ACCEPTED.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());
    }
}
```

when i run `mvn clean install`, I see that tests runs and fails and cargo is no where in logs saying it was deploying.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Pryme REST Services Integration Test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ integration ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/harith/IdeaProjects/pryme_services/inventory/integration/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ integration ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ integration ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ integration ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/harith/IdeaProjects/pryme_services/inventory/integration/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ integration ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/harith/IdeaProjects/pryme_services/inventory/integration/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ integration ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/harith/IdeaProjects/pryme_services/inventory/integration/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.yahoo.pryme_services.inventory.integration.TestHelloIT
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.469 sec <<< FAILURE!
testHello(com.yahoo.pryme_services.inventory.integration.TestHelloIT)  Time elapsed: 0.435 sec  <<< ERROR!
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:229)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:655)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:652)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:652)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:291)
    at com.yahoo.pryme_services.inventory.integration.TestHelloIT.testHello(TestHelloIT.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:321)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:227)
    ... 40 more


Results :
```

**Question**

How can I make sure cargo deploys the war before tests actually run

Answer (score 2):

So, it turns out that your issue is with the name of your test. Rename it *HelloIT* from *TestHelloIT* and it should work.

To understand why this is the case, let's remind ourselves of Maven's lifecycle:

```
validate
compile
test
package
integration-test
verify
install
deploy
```

And you'll notice that your test is running and failing in the Surefire plugin. The Surefire plugin runs in the test phase, that is, it is running before your application is even packaged, let alone deployed, to your container in the integration-test phase.

You've actually correctly named your test for the Failsafe plugin, which is the one you wanted it to run in for the integration-test phase. By default, it picks up classes named `**/IT*.java`, `**/*IT.java`, and `**/*ITCase.java`.

However, the naming convention for the Surefire plugin is `**/Test*.java`, `**/*Test.java`, and `**/*TestCase.java`. So what you've managed to do is name the test so that it is picked up by both plugins, and since Surefire runs and fails first it isn't even getting to the point that your container would deploy.

The rest looks fine so that should work.

Comment: Thanks @mardoz, seems like it is not running it in test phase and I can see the tomcat being deployed. But now After the tomcat is deployed I do not see any `HelloIT.java` being run at all. Am I still missing anything?